# Painting app doesn't paint on mobile browses

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've a painting app where users paint on the screen. It works well on desktop browsers. Unfortunately, it doesn't work on mobile browsers and the user cannot paint. I suspect that I'm not using the mobile JavaScript events correctly.

This is a JavaScript problem.

Here is the link:

https://fascinatingdreams.com/fairy-tales/drawing

And here is the code:

```js
const paintCanvas = document.querySelector('.js-paint');
const context = paintCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.lineCap = 'round';

const colorPicker = document.querySelector('.js-color-picker');

colorPicker.addEventListener('change', event => {
  context.strokeStyle = event.target.value;
});

const lineWidthRange = document.querySelector('.js-line-range');
const lineWidthLabel = document.querySelector('.js-range-value');

lineWidthRange.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const width = event.target.value;
  lineWidthLabel.innerHTML = width;
  context.lineWidth = width;
});

let x = 0,
  y = 0;
let isMouseDown = false;

const stopDrawing = () => {
  isMouseDown = false;
}
const startDrawing = event => {
  isMouseDown = true;
  [x, y] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY];
}
const drawLine = event => {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    const newX = event.offsetX;
    const newY = event.offsetY;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(newX, newY);
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drawLine);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);

paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", startDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchend", stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", drawLine);
```

```css
.paint-canvas {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.color-picker {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input class="js-color-picker  color-picker" type="color" />
  <input class="js-line-range" max="72" min="1" type="range" value="1" />
  <label class="js-range-value">1</label>Px
  <canvas class="js-paint  paint-canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
</p>
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added mobile events, but it doesn't work. Also, it is a Javascript problem.

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging for the device? There might be an error on the browser console. See [remote debugging for Android](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/) for example.

Comment: surface pen as well as windows touch input doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `event.touches[0]` to get `offsetX` and `offsetY` instead.

Note that `event.touches[0]` does not return `offsetX` and `offsetY` directly, so we need to have some calculations.

```
const getXY = (event) => {
  let [offsetX, offsetY] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY]
  if (event.touches && event.touches[0]) {
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    offsetX = (event.touches[0].clientX - rect.left)
    offsetY = (event.touches[0].clientY - rect.top)
  }
  return [offsetX, offsetY]
}
```

```js
const getXY = (event) => {
  let [offsetX, offsetY] = [event.offsetX, event.offsetY]
  if (event.touches && event.touches[0]) {
    const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    offsetX = (event.touches[0].clientX - rect.left)
    offsetY = (event.touches[0].clientY - rect.top)
  }
  return [offsetX, offsetY]
}

const paintCanvas = document.querySelector('.js-paint');
const context = paintCanvas.getContext('2d');
context.lineCap = 'round';

const colorPicker = document.querySelector('.js-color-picker');

colorPicker.addEventListener('change', event => {
  context.strokeStyle = event.target.value;
});

const lineWidthRange = document.querySelector('.js-line-range');
const lineWidthLabel = document.querySelector('.js-range-value');

lineWidthRange.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const width = event.target.value;
  lineWidthLabel.innerHTML = width;
  context.lineWidth = width;
});

let x = 0,
  y = 0;
let isMouseDown = false;

const stopDrawing = () => {
  isMouseDown = false;
}
const startDrawing = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
  isMouseDown = true;
  [x, y] = getXY(event);
}
const drawLine = event => {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    const [newX, newY] = getXY(event);
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x, y);
    context.lineTo(newX, newY);
    context.stroke();
    //[x, y] = [newX, newY];
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
  }
}

paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drawLine);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener('mouseout', stopDrawing);

paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchstart", startDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchend", stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchcancel", stopDrawing);
paintCanvas.addEventListener("touchmove", drawLine);

window.addEventListener('mousewheel', (e) => {
  if (isMouseDown) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
.paint-canvas {
  border: 1px black solid;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.color-picker {
  margin: 1rem 1rem 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input class="js-color-picker  color-picker" type="color" />
  <input class="js-line-range" max="72" min="1" type="range" value="1" />
  <label class="js-range-value">1</label>Px
  <canvas class="js-paint  paint-canvas" height="200" width="200"></canvas>
</p>
```

Comment: this is working fine with touch and pen input on windows too. you still need to cancel event propagation too because otherwise the window would scroll while you draw.

Comment: @GottZ I tried "event.stopPropagation();" right after "if (event.touches && event.touches[0]) {", but it doesn't work, do you know how it is done?

Comment: `event.stopPropagation` does not work, you can update `mousewheel` event on `window` with `e.preventDefault()` when `isMouseDown === true`.  By the way, I updated that part in my answer too @sp2012

Comment: But @NickVu, does it work from your part? Because, on my phone, when the user draws, the screen still scrolls up and down.

Comment: I just added `event.preventDefault` on `startDrawing` as well. That would help to avoid dragging behaviour on touch devices

Comment: I recorded a video of the behavior before you added it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ymo9YHblSRk will check again now.

Comment: it is working perfectly fine now. :)

Comment: hi @GottZ, it's awesome for a real test! thank you!~

Comment: Nice work @NickVu! It now works fine.

Comment: If you think my answer is useful, please help me to mark it as a solution. That would help all other people having the same problem as well as give a little support to me and this community. Thank you~ :D @sp2012

Comment: I agree. this answers the original question and should be awarded with the reputation it deserves.

Comment: @NickVu I apologize for the delayed mark. I wanted to mark it as a solution, but then it slipped my mind. I marked it now.

Comment: No problem!~ :D